# How can I use databricks utils functions in PyCharm? I can't find appropriate pip package

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm, databricks

PyCharm IDE. I want to use `dbutils.widgets.get()` in a module and than to import this module to databricks. I already tried with `pip install databricks-client` `pip install databricks-utils` and `pip install DBUtils`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `dbutils` is available only as a part of the [databricks-connect package](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html). Its documentation contains detailed description on [how to setup PyCharm](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#pycharm) to work with it.  It also [covers](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html#access-dbutils) on how to use the `dbutils`.

You may need to define following wrapper to be able to use `dbutils` locally and on Databricks:

```
def get_dbutils(spark):
  from pyspark.dbutils import DBUtils
  return DBUtils(spark)

get_dbutils().fs.cp('file:/home/user/data.csv', 'dbfs:/uploads')
```